# Replicate rows by decrementing one of the columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe with a few columns. For simplicity, lets consider only two column `id` and `num`:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5 |
| 1002 | 3 |

The goal here is to create multiple rows for the `id` column but decrementing the `num` column. Below is the **expected output:**

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1001 | 3 |
| 1001 | 4 |
| 1001 | 5 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1002 | 2 |
| 1002 | 3 |

**Current solution:**

1. Create a UDF that creates a list for all the missing values like so:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | [1,2,3,4,5] |
| 1002 | [1,2,3] |

2. Then use explode to create those replicated rows.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I don't want to use UDF unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sequence` to generate a range of numbers start from literal 1 to the `num` value

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('num', F.explode(F.sequence(F.lit(1), F.col('num'))))
```

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
+----+---+
|  id|num|
+----+---+
|1001|  5|
|1002|  3|
+----+---+
```

If you wanted to repeat the rows `num` times, you can employ `Pandas_udf`. You dont need to necessarily create a num column with arrays to replicate row.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
def repeat_rows(iterator:Iterator[pd.DataFrame])->Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
  for pdf in iterator:
    yield(pdf.loc[pdf.index.repeat(pdf['num'])].reset_index(drop=True))
df.mapInPandas(repeat_rows, df.schema).withColumn('num', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col('id')).orderBy(col('id')))).show()

+----+---+
|  id|num|
+----+---+
|1001|  1|
|1001|  2|
|1001|  3|
|1001|  4|
|1001|  5|
|1002|  1|
|1002|  2|
|1002|  3|
+----+---+
```

Comment: Ooops, see my edits. I had missed something. Hope it adds you new method